# How to use Search Places in Here Android Starter SDK using SearchRequest Class

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, here-api

We are going to implement Search Places functionality on Here Map Android Starter SDK, but we are facing problem on search places using SearchRequest method, getting error as #BAD_REQUEST,

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("shopping");
searchRequest.setSearchCenter(m_map.getCenter());
searchRequest.setSearchArea(new GeoCoordinate(18.467518, 73.777694), 5000);
searchRequest.execute(discoveryResultPageListener);
```

Getting Result as

```
     private ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage> discoveryResultPageListener = new ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(DiscoveryResultPage discoveryResultPage, ErrorCode errorCode) {
        if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE) {
            /* No error returned,let's handle the results */
            m_placeDetailButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            s_ResultList = discoveryResultPage.getItems();
            for (DiscoveryResult item : s_ResultList) {
                if (item.getResultType() == DiscoveryResult.ResultType.PLACE) {
                    PlaceLink placeLink = (PlaceLink) item;
                    addMarkerAtPlace(placeLink);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(m_activity,
                    "ERROR:Discovery search request returned return error code+ " + errorCode,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Also we have implemented Here Maps Android SDK API on premium version,In that Search Places working fine. but in Premium version android APK size has been more than 65MB.

So how we can use Search Places in Starter SDK.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Specify search location using either `setSearchCenter` or `setSearchArea`, if you use them at the same time you will get `BAD_REQUEST` error.

Premium SDK includes native libraries for `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` architectures. You can [split ABIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) and generate multiple apks if you want to reduce final app's size.